# C++ variadic expansion using deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates

I'm developing a library that deals with non typed C functions (SQLite) and I want to strong typing it.

The idea is to have a `FieldDef` strong type that allow user to tie raw types like int, double and std::string to weak db types.
My problem is that the semantic of the library is very heavy, and I would like to add some automatic type deduction.

So I have a bunch of "basic types":

```
namespace FieldType {
  struct Integer { using rawtype = int; };
  struct Real{ using rawtype = double; };
  struct Text{ using rawtype = std::string; };
  struct Blob{ using rawtype = std::vector<uint8_t>; };
}
```

I also have a `insert` and a `query` functions that allow inserting and querying the tables without using SQL statements. The query will be plain select. Anyway. The intended use is:

```
FieldDef<FieldType::Integer> mId = makeFieldDef("id", FieldType::Integer()).primaryKey().autoincrement();
FieldDef<FieldType::Text> mName = makeFieldDef("name", FieldType::Text());
FieldDef<FieldType::Integer> mValue = makeFieldDef("value", FieldType::Integer());

SQLiteTable::insert(std::make_tuple(mName, mValue), std::make_tuple(record.name, record.value));

std::vector<Record> r;
SQLiteTable::query
            (std::make_tuple(mName, mValue), [&r](std::tuple<std::string, int> res) {
        r.push_back(Record{std::get<0>(res), std::get<1>(res)});
});
```

I implemented the insert this way:

```
template <typename ...Ts, typename ...Us>
bool insert (std::tuple<Ts...> def, std::tuple<Us...> values) {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "INSERT INTO " << mName << "("
                                  << buildSqlInsertFieldList<0>(def)
                                  << ") VALUES ("
                                  << buildSqlInsertValuesListPlaceholder<0>(values)
                                  << ");";
    auto stmt = newStatement(ss.str());
    bindAllValues<0>(stmt.get(), values);
    return execute(stmt.get());
}
```

This works fine, the problems come with query:

```
template <typename ...Ts, typename ...Us>
void query(std::tuple<Ts...> def, std::function<void(std::tuple<Us...>)> resultFeedbackFunc) {
   ...
}
```

When calling it the compiler is unable to correctly deduce the types, so I guess it requires a pedantic construction:

```
SQLiteTable::query<FieldType::Text, FieldType::Integer, /* whatever */> (...)
```

It's unpractical and verbose.

1. Would it be possible to simplify the query function?
   Since we have a constrain in the usage, that is the `Us` pack can only be some type compatible with `FieldType::*:rawtype`, I am asking if it would be possible to use some construct that unpacks and apply a method. In case of `insert`, could it be simplified with something like:

   ```
   template<typename Ts...>
   bool insert (std::tuple<Ts...> def, std::tuple<Ts::rawtype ...> values)
   ```
2. instead of using tuples, what about using Variadic Packs? I haven't tested it but I fear that using something like

   ```
   template<typename Ts..., typename Us....>
   bool insert (Ts... def, Us ... values)
   ```

would confuse the compiler and would make things worse.
What do you think?

3. If it is possible to use the actual implementation of query, what would be a workaround to make the usage code more expressive?

---

Here are some details about the code, to explain:

The query function is implemented using the following pseudocode:

```
template <typename ...Ts, typename ...Us>
void query(std::tuple<Ts...> def, std::function<void(std::tuple<Us...>)> resultFeedbackFunc) {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "SELECT " << buildSqlInsertFieldList<0>(def) << " FROM " << mName <<";";
    auto stmt = newStatement(ss.str());

    auto r = execute(stmt.get());
    SQLiteException::throwIfNotOk(r, db()->handle());

    while (hasData(stmt.get())) {
        auto nColumns = columnCount(stmt.get());
        if (nColumns != sizeof...(Ts))
            throw std::runtime_error("Column count differs from data size");

        std::tuple<Us...> res;
        getAllValues<0>(stmt.get(), res);
        resultFeedbackFunc(res);
    }
};
```

`Statement` is an opaque type that hides the `sqlite` statement structure, as do the other functions used in the `query` method `newStatement`, `execute` and `columnsCount`. The function `getAllValues` uses recursion to fill the `tuple`. So the functor `resultFeedbackFunc()` will be called for every row of the database. So the client code can, for example, fill a container (like a vector).

---

**Update**:

I followed  @bolov's solution, and added @massimiliano-jones's improvements.

This is the correct implementation of the inner call to the feedback function:

```
resultFeedbackFunc(getValueR<decltype (std::get<Is>(def).rawType())>
      (stmt.get(), Is)...);
```

`getValueR` makes the internal call to `sqlite_column_xxx(sqlite3_stmt *, int index)`. If I understand correctly, the unpacking works because the arguments list is a valid context for unpacking. If I wanted the calls to be made outside the arguments, I had to make a folding (or workaround since I'm using c++11).

Comment: for those interested, the project is published here: https://github.com/studiofuga/mSqliteCpp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's difficult to give specific help as there are important code parts missing from your post.

However here are my 2 cents. Please note I've filled with my imagination the missing parts of your code.

First of all you need to get rid of the `std::function` argument. Use `std::function` only if you need the type erasure it provides. In your case (at least from the code you've shown) you don't need it. So we replace that with a simple `template <class F>` parameter. This solves the deduction problem.

Now when you pass an invalid function object you will get a compilation error deep in the bowls of your `query` implementation. If you don't want that and you want to fail fast, then there are some options. I chose to show you a SFINAE approach with `decltype`.

```
namespace FieldType
{
  struct Integer { using rawtype = int; };
  struct Real{ using rawtype = double; };
  struct Text{ using rawtype = std::string; };
};

template <class FT>
struct FieldDef
{
    using Type = FT;
    using RawTye = typename Type::rawtype;

    auto getRaw() -> RawTye { return {}; }
};

template <class... Args, class F, std::size_t... Is>
auto query_impl(std::tuple<Args...> def, F f, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    -> decltype(f(std::get<Is>(def).getRaw()...), std::declval<void>())
{
   f(std::get<Is>(def).getRaw()...);
}

template <class... Args, class F>
auto query(std::tuple<Args...> def, F f)
    -> decltype(query_impl(def, f, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{}))
{
   query_impl(def, f, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{});
}
```

```
auto test()
{
    FieldDef<FieldType::Text> mName = {};
    FieldDef<FieldType::Integer> mValue = {};

    query(std::make_tuple(mName, mValue), [](std::string, int) {});      // OK

    query(std::make_tuple(mName, mValue), [](std::string, int, int) {}); // Error
    query(std::make_tuple(mName, mValue), [](int, int) {});              // Error
}
```

The invalid calls fail with a message akin to:

> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 'query'
> ...   
> note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with Args = ...]:
>   no matching function for call to 'query_impl'
> ...
> ```

Regarding your point 2. That would be not deductible. And even if it would be, you want to group the parameters for readability. I.e. you want `insert({a, b}, {c, d})` instead of `insert(a, b, c, d)`.

I don't understand your point 3.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the kind of interface I was thinking. I put some other detail in the question, but most of the assumptions you did are right. I'm struggling on trying to adapt your structure to the actual code but I think I have quite all the info I needed, thank you. About 2), ok as I guessed. forget about 3), since we have an elegant solution we don't need any workaround.

Answer (score 2):

> 2. instead of using tuples, what about using Variadic Packs?

you may try something like

```
template<typename T,typename V>
struct FieldInsert{ V const& ref; };

template<typename T>
struct FieldDef
{
  template<typename V>
  auto operator()( V const& value ) const{ return FieldInsert<T,V>{value}; }
};

template<typename... T>
bool insert( T... args )
{
  // defines buildSqlInsertFieldList and buildSqlInsertValuesListPlaceholder the obvious way ...
}

// to be used as

SQLiteTable::insert( mName(record.name), mValue(record.value) );
```

this is more readable than the tuple version: firstly, fields count is automatically equal to values count, then, each value comes next to its field, it supports 'default' field values ( via, say, `mName()`), ...

---

regarding `query()`, more expressive alternatives might be

```
// return a lazily evaluated input-range (or a coroutine?)
for( auto item: SQLiteTable::query( mName, mValue ) )
  // ...

// and/or query() simply returns a forwarding wrapper exposing, say, a chainable interface ...
SQLiteTable::query( mName, mValue ).for_each([]/*lambda*/);
```

Comment: I like your implementation for `insert`, thanks. About `query`, I'm trying to implement @bolov's solution but I am swamped on building the call to the functor :-) Thanks.